# Automatic re-compilation with asset management tools

Tags: php, javascript, css, assets, assetic

I have been looking into incorporating an asset management/pipelining tool (probably [Assetic](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic)) into my PHP project.

Since assets can be grouped into collections or wildcard-based paths using such tools, if I wanted to set up a watch process that re-compiled/minified only those source files that had changed, how would I do that given that assets have to be looked up by name (see example below)?

(I noticed that for Symfony there's a watch task for Assetic but I'm not sure that it re-compiles only the changed file(s) and also I would have to make it work outside of Symfony since my app uses the CodeIgniter framework.)

In Assetic, you can create a wildcard-based asset, e.g.:

```
new GlobAsset('/path/to/compass-sources/*')
```

You can tell it to send the assets through a filter (Compass in this example) and then output the result (CSS) to a folder like `public/css`.

Let's say I set up the watch process using node.js's `fs.watch` so that I can theoretically tell Assetic to re-compile a particular asset whenever one of its source files changes.

Since my node.js script would only know the name of the actual file that changed (e.g. `compass-sources/layout.scss`), how could I look up which AssetCollection or GlobAsset that particular file belonged to (say an asset called `global-styles`) in order to recompile it?

I'm open to alternatives here. I looked at grunt and may very well use [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) to handle the file watching, but I like the idea of using Assetic because the project is in PHP and I think that will be easier on future PHP developers working on the system who may not be familiar with node.js. It seems grunt take a different approach where assets don't necessarily go in named bundles. Mostly I want to understand the conceptual approach of named asset bundles (like in Assetic) as it relates to my goal of recompiling assets whenever the source files change.

Comment: I recently discovered the `find_asset` method of [Sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets) which seems to be what I was looking for, but Assetic does not seem to have any such method; an oversight, perhaps?